# Spin.js .stop() function problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, preloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable scope issue with javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613176/variable-scope-issue-with-javascript-function)

I am using spin.js with jquery. My spinner starts when an element in a dropdown menu is selected, and should stop when the query returns the data. I have tried  `$('.spinner').spin(false);` as well as `$("#spinnerContainer").spinner.stop();`but nothing seems to be working. Below is my code:

```
function spinnerInit() {
    var opts = {
        lines: 13,
        length: 7,
        width: 4,
        radius: 10,
        corners: 1,
        rotate: 0,
        color: '#000',
        speed: 1,
        trail: 60,
        shadow: false,
        hwaccel: false,
        className: 'spinner',
        zIndex: 2e9,
        top: 'auto',
        left: 'auto',
        visibility: true
    };

    $('#spinnerContainer').after(new Spinner(opts).spin().el);
}
$('.categories-select').click(function() {
    spinnerInit();
    $("#spinnerContainer").spinner.stop();

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="spinnerContainer" class="spinner">
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See [Variable scope issue with javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613176/variable-scope-issue-with-javascript-function) on how to use Spinner correctly. There is no `spinner` property on the just created `$("#spinnerContainer")` object

Comment: without seeing plugin code or docs...  guessing this might work ` `$("#spinnerContainer").spinner('stop');` A link to docs would help